# Getting error while hosting WCF service when add <trust level="Full" />

Tags: c#, wcf, dynamics-crm

I am trying to host WCF service in "hostgator". I want to set Trust level because I am getting security permission error.

When I set `Trust Level` in `web.config`, I am getting an error.

`web.config`:

```
<location allowOverride="true">
    <system.web>
        <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.2"/>
        <identity impersonate="false" />
        <authentication mode="None" />
        <httpRuntime maxUrlLength="1024" relaxedUrlToFileSystemMapping="true"/>

        <customErrors mode="Off"></customErrors>
        <securityPolicy>
            <trustLevel name="Full" policyFile="internal"/>
        </securityPolicy>
    </system.web>
</location>
```

Error:

> An application error occurred on the server. The current custom error
>   settings for this application prevent the details of the application
>   error from being viewed remotely (for security reasons). It could,
>   however, be viewed by browsers running on the local server machine.

Can anybody suggest a way to solve this?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4xJOz.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per [HostGator FAQ](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwinjbPQqKrOAhUDlR4KHcI1CMQQFggrMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fsupport.hostgator.com%2Farticles%2Fplesk%2Fwindows-shared-hosting-information%2Fwindows-shared-frequently-asked-questions-plesk-10&usg=AFQjCNHovFqnrmNPdpBI4FKYlvYmLymSxg&sig2=Z4HE2_unqWjjvZKGS5P17g&bvm=bv.128617741,d.dmo) you must run in partial trust using their shared hosting:

> No. The applications must be published in Medium Trust in order to run
>   on the Windows Shared Server.

You're not going to be able to use the SDK in a medium trust environment from what I've read.  As Dynamics CRM 2016 expands its support for its REST API that may become an option for you.